# how to combine array element after unwinding in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am fetching all the user's post and his friends post and combining them through this code, now every post has a likes field which is an array of ids' that stores ids' of people who have liked the post, I want that every post have a property that has all the users fetched through that id. I tried unwinding (`$unwind`) likes array and fetching all the users using `$lookup` but combining all the users in a single array messes up with `allCombinedPosts` property.

```
const userWithAllPosts = await User.aggregate([
          {
            $match: {
              _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id),
            },
          },
          {
            $lookup: {
              from: "posts",
              localField: "_id",
              foreignField: "userId",
              pipeline: [
                {
                  $lookup: {
                    from: "comments",
                    localField: "_id",
                    foreignField: "postId",
                    pipeline: [
                      {
                        $lookup: {
                          from: "users",
                          localField: "commenterId",
                          foreignField: "_id",
                          as: "commentOwner",
                        },
                      },
                    ],
                    as: "postComments",
                  },
                },
              ],
              as: "myPosts",
            },
          },
          {
            $lookup: {
              from: "posts",
              localField: "friends",
              foreignField: "userId",
              pipeline: [
                {
                  $lookup: {
                    from: "comments",
                    localField: "_id",
                    foreignField: "postId",
                    pipeline: [
                      {
                        $lookup: {
                          from: "users",
                          localField: "commenterId",
                          foreignField: "_id",
                          as: "commentOwner",
                        },
                      },
                    ],
                    as: "postComments",
                  },
                },
              ],
              as: "allFriendsPosts",
            },
          },

          {
            $set: {
              allPostsCombined: {
                $concatArrays: ["$myPosts", "$allFriendsPosts"],
              },
            },
          },
          { $unwind: "$allPostsCombined" },
          {
            $sort: {
              "allPostsCombined.createdAt": -1,
            },
          },
          {
            $group: {
              _id: "$_id",
              name: { $first: "$name" },
              email: { $first: "$email" },
              bio: { $first: "$bio" },
              livesIn: { $first: "$livesIn" },
              profilePic: { $first: "$profilePic" },
              coverPic: { $first: "$coverPic" },
              coverPic: { $first: "$coverPic" },
              createdAt: { $first: "$createdAt" },
              updatedAt: { $first: "$updatedAt" },
              allPostsCombined: { $push: "$allPostsCombined" },
            },
          },
        ]);
```

Comment: Would you elaborate on _"messes up"_?  What is the current output?  What is the desired output?

Comment: Having 6 `$lookup` in a query smells like a poor database design. MongoDB is not a relational database, NoSQL databases are not optimized for joins. You may review your design.

Comment: Instead of `$unwind, $sort, $group` have a look at `$sortArray`